# Find difference in two python dataframes based on specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, difference

I want to compare the dataframes based on the `S/N` and `Metric` column to find the values that changed from the most recent value in df2:

```
df1
#    S/N   Age  Metric
# 0  001  2.59    1.01
# 1  002  3.57    2.42
# 2  003  3.99    3.12


df2
#    S/N   Age  Metric
# 0  001  2.46    4.29
# 1  001  2.50    2.46
# 2  001  2.54    2.47
# 3  002  1.78    1.24
# 4  002  1.82    2.42
# 5  003  3.57    1.91
# 6  003  3.61    2.47
# 7  003  3.65    1.24
```

I am looking for the following dataframe:

```
   S/N   Age  Metric
0  001  2.59    1.01
2  003  3.99    3.12
```

### Data

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "S/N": ['001', '002', '003'],
    "Age": [2.59, 3.57, 3.99],
    "Metric": [1.01, 2.42, 3.12]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "S/N": ['001','001','001', '002','002', '003', '003', '003'],
    "Age": [2.46, 2.50, 2.54, 1.78, 1.82, 3.57, 3.61, 3.65],
    "Metric": [4.29, 2.46, 2.47, 1.24, 2.42, 1.91, 2.47, 1.24]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are roughly two steps involved here. First you need to compare `df1` and `df2`, and based on that comparison you want to filter your data.

### Step 1: Comparing

To compare `df1` with `df2` according to column `Metric`, you run:

```
df1['Metric'] != df2['Metric']
0    True
1    False   
2    True
3    False
```

### Step 2: Filtering

In pandas, you can filter rows with a pandas Series ("single column dataframe") that contains only `True` or `False` values:

```
inds = df1['Metric'] != df2['Metric']
df2.loc[inds, :]
     S/N   Age  Metric
# 0  001  2.46    4.29
# 2  003  2.00    2.47
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. The two dataframes are not always the same size, so I need to link the S/N with the Metric in the comparrison.